# How to test certificate validation with OCSP address in powershell

Tags: powershell, certificate, x509certificate, ocsp

I have certificate and when I try to test my digital signature code one error raised for OCSP validation. Now I want to check OCSP address and my certificate validation with powershell to test and find my error.

I need the powershell command to check validation of my certificate with OCSP address.

Comment: there is no built-in OCSP validation tool in PowerShell. You may need to use 3rd party PS modules.

Comment: @Crypt32 we have certutil in command prompt

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have certutil tools in cmd for test a certificate validity with ocsp or crt file

Certutil -path 'address of csertificate'

When you run this command windows open a little tools for test your certificate

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/certutil